# Joining specific parts of text from two files in third?

Tags: bash, shell, join, awk, grep

My question is based again, on linux shell programming, and this time, I have two textual files, with about 17,000 lines in each.

In first file i have lines which have this form:

```
[*] 11004, e01c5dee8efb188af91fb989a1039a12, isabelleann86@yahoo.com
```

And second file has form for each line:

```
e01c5dee8efb188af91fb989a1039a12:nathan09
```

Now I want to create third file from these two, to have form of:

```
isabelleann86@yahoo.com:nathan09
```

But notation please, hash e01c5dee8efb188af91fb989a1039a12 must correspond to both lines in first and second file, not like creating line with email_1 and password_3421.

Email from file one, and password from file two, where line has the same hash value?

I know it is maybe possible by using grep/awk combination, but I just do not know how to form it.

Comment: i just told i know it can be done through grep and awk, but still do not know how to format command, and yeah, really bad idea to work one line at time also, as i have about 17 thousands lines in each file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk` with multiple delimiters:

```
awk -F "[ ,:]+" 'FNR==NR { a[$3]=$4; next } $1 in a { print a[$1], $2 }' OFS=":" file1 file2 > file3
```

Results; contents of `file3`:

```
isabelleann86@yahoo.com:nathan09
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$(NF-1)]=$NF;next}   
    $1"," in a {print a[$1","] FS $NF}' file1 FS=:  file2
```